# Script to clone/snapshot Docker Containers including their Data?

Tags: shell, web-applications, docker, clone, docker-compose

I would like to clone a dockerized application including all its data, which uses three containers in this example: 1) a web application container such as a CMS, 2) a database container and 3) a data-volume container (using docker volumes).

With docker-compose, I can easily create identical instances of these containers with just the initial data. But what, if I want to clone a set of running containers on the same server, including all its accumulated data, in a similar way as I would clone a KVM container? With KVM I would suspend or shutdown the VM, clone with something like virt-clone and then start the cloned guest, which has all the same data as the original.

One use case would be to create a clone/snapshot of a running development web-server before making major changes or before installing new versions of plugins.

With Docker, this does not seem to be so straightforward, as data is not automatically copied together with its container. Ideally I would like to do something simple like `docker-compose clone` and end up with a second set of containers identical to the first, including all their data. Neither Docker nor docker-compose provides a clone command (as of version 1.8), thus I would need to consider various approaches, like backing up & restoring the data/database or using a third party tool like Flocker.

Related to this is the question on how to do something similar to KVM snapshots of a dockerized app, with the ability to easily return to a previous state. Preferably the cloning, snapshotting and reverting should be possible with minimal downtime.

What would be the preferred Docker way of accomplishing these things?

Edit: Based on the first answer, I will make my question a little more specific in order to hopefully arrive at programmatic steps to be able to do something like `docker-compose-clone` and `docker-compose-snapshot` using a bash or python script. Cloning the content of the docker volumes seems to be the key to this, as the containers themselves are basically cloned each time I run docker-compose on the same yaml file.

Generally my full-clone script would need to

1. duplicate the directory containing the docker-compose file
2. temporarily stop the containers
3. create (but not necessarily run) the second set of containers
4. ***determine the data-volumes to be duplicated***
5. backup these data-volumes
6. restore the data-volumes into the cloned data container
7. start the second set of containers

   - Would this be the correct way to go about it and how should I implement this? I'm especially not sure on how to do step 4 (*determine the data-volumes to be duplicated*) in a script, as the command `docker volume ls` will only be available in Docker 1.9.
   - How could I do something similar to KVM snapshots using this approach? (possibly using COW filesystem features from ZFS, which my Docker install is already using).

Answer (score 0):

With docker you would keep all of your state in volumes. Your containers can be recreated from images as long as they re-use the same volumes (either from the host or a data-volume container).

I'm not aware of an easy way to export volumes from a data-volume container. I know that the docker 1.9 release is going to be adding some top-level apis for interacting with volumes, but I'm not sure if export will be available immediately.

If you're using a host volume, you could manage the state externally from docker.

Comment: Yes, as indicated in the question, I am using data-volume containers already (I made the wording a bit clearer now). I would rather not use host containers, as they are less portable. AFAIK Docker 1.9 will add `docker volume create, inspect, ls, rm` [commands](https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/man) which do not quite provide the needed features for cloning. Would you have any suggestions on how to _determine the data-volumes to be duplicated_ within a script?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I'm using the following script to clone a dockerized CMS web-application Concrete5.7, based on the approach outlined above. It creates a second set of identical containers using docker-compose, then it backs up just the data from the data volumes, and restores it to the data containers in the second set.

This could serve as an example for developing a more generalised script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# This script will clone a set of containers including all its data

# the docker-compose.yml is in the PROJ_ORIG directory
# - do not use capital letters or underscores for clone suffix, 
#   as docker-compose will modify or remove these
PROJ_ORIG="c5app"
PROJ_CLONE="${PROJ_ORIG}003"

# 1. duplicate the directory containing the docker-compose file
cd /opt/docker/compose/concrete5.7/
cp -Rv ${PROJ_ORIG}/ ${PROJ_CLONE}/

# 2. temporarily stop the containers
cd ${PROJ_ORIG}
docker-compose stop

# 3. create, run and stop the second set of containers 
#    (docker-compose does not have a create command)
cd ../${PROJ_CLONE}
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose stop

# 4. determine the data-volumes to be duplicated
#   a) examine which containers are designated data containers
#   b) then use docker inspect to determine the relevant directories
#   c) store destination directories & process them for backup and clone
#
# In this appliaction we use two data containers 
# (here we used DATA as part of the name):
# $ docker-compose ps | grep DATA
#     c5app_DB-DATA_1    /true                            Exit 0
#     c5app_WEB-DATA_1   /true                            Exit 0
#
# $ docker inspect ${PROJ_ORIG}_WEB-DATA_1 | grep Destination
#     "Destination": "/var/www/html",
#     "Destination": "/etc/apache2",
#
# $ docker inspect ${PROJ_ORIG}_DB-DATA_1 | grep Destination
#     "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",

# these still need to be determined manually from examining 
# the docker-compose.yml or using the commands in 4.
DATA_SUF1="_WEB-DATA_1"
VOL1_1="/etc/apache2"
VOL1_2="/var/www/html"

DATA_SUF2="_DB-DATA_1"
VOL2_1="/var/lib/mysql"

# 5. Backup Data:
docker run --rm --volumes-from ${PROJ_ORIG}${DATA_SUF1} -v ${PWD}:/clone debian tar -cpzf /clone/clone${DATA_SUF1}.tar.gz ${VOL1_1} ${VOL1_2}
docker run --rm --volumes-from ${PROJ_ORIG}${DATA_SUF2} -v ${PWD}:/clone debian tar -cpzf /clone/clone${DATA_SUF2}.tar.gz ${VOL2_1}

# 6. Clone Data:
# existing files in volumes need to be deleted before restoring, 
# as the installation may have created additional files during initial run,
# which do not get overwritten during restore
docker run --rm --volumes-from ${PROJ_CLONE}${DATA_SUF1} -v ${PWD}:/clone debian bash -c "rm -rf ${VOL1_1}/* ${VOL1_2}/* && tar -xpf /clone/clone${DATA_SUF1}.tar.gz"
docker run --rm --volumes-from ${PROJ_CLONE}${DATA_SUF2} -v ${PWD}:/clone debian bash -c "rm -rf ${VOL2_1}/* && tar -xpf /clone/clone${DATA_SUF2}.tar.gz"

# 7. Start Cloned Containers:
docker-compose start

# 8. Remove tar archives
rm -v clone${DATA_SUF1}.tar.gz
rm -v clone${DATA_SUF2}.tar.gz
```

Its been tested and works, but still has the following limitations:

- the data-volumes to be duplicated need to be determined manually and
- the script needs to be modified, depending on the number of data-containers and data-volumes
- there is no snap-shot/restore capability

I welcome any suggestions for improvements (especially step 4.). Or, if someone would come up with a different, better approach I would accept that as an answer instead.

The application used in this example, together with the docker-compose.yml file can be found [here.](https://github.com/chriswayg/concrete5.7)

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, there is a port of docker's open source container project available from Windocks that does what you need. There are two options:

1. Smaller sized databases are copied into containers via an Add database command specified while building the image. After that every container built from that receives the database automatically.
2. For large databases, there is a cloning functionality. The databases are cloned during the creation of containers and the clones are done in seconds even for terabyte size DBs. Deleting a container also removes the clone automatically. Right now its only available for SQL Server though.

   See [here](http://windocks.com) for more details on the database adding and cloning.